# Can't upload large files using XHR and FormData

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, xmlhttprequest

I have created simple script using XMLHttpRequest. It sends text and (optionally) file. It works but problem is that large files (above 50MB) are not accepted. I thought that problem was with PHP's `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` but it doesn't (I set it up 512MB). I don't know what to do now... Any ideas?

```
function publishPost() {

    if (!event) { event = window.event; }
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('SelectedFile', document.querySelector('#post input').files[0]);

    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
    x.setRequestHeader('TEXT', post.innerHTML);
    x.onload = function() {
        if (x.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (x.responseText == '1') {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert('Error: ' + x.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    x.send(data);

}
```

And PHP:

```
$text = strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_TEXT']);
$file = $_FILES['SelectedFile']['name'];
$info = pathinfo($file);
$uniqid = uniqid();

if (!empty($file)) {

    $newfile = '../files/'.$uniqid.'.'.$info['extension'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['SelectedFile']['tmp_name'], $newfile)) {
        $file = $uniqid.'.'.$info['extension'];
    }

}

// Adding to Database
```

My error is `Undefined index: SelectedFile`

Comment: Have you checked to make sure it successfully uploads 'small' files? (small being in this case files which you are certain it should have no trouble uploading due to size). The error message you posted makes it sound like a different issue to file size. I once encountered a similar problem, and was forced to split the file into chunks and upload each separately.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly with small files. I have checked headers that are send to PHP script and everything looks fine both with small and large files. That why it is weird. If it works with small files and not with large the only reasonable issue is due to file size.

Comment: I am having the same issue with files above 4MB, small files upload fine though? I am using ASP.Net MVC however. Did you ever find a solution or the cause?